# ServiceStack ServiceExceptionHandler.Add method does not exists?

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I am using ServiceStack version 3.9.71 and I cannot find the "Add" method. Is the documentation on the [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) outdated? What should I do in order to make it work?

```cs
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.ServiceExceptionHandler.Add((httpReq, request, exception) => {
        return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, exception);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at the v4 documentation. You need the [v3 documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStackv3/ServiceStackv3/wiki/Error-Handling#customized-error-handling).

```cs
//Handle Exceptions occurring in Services:
this.ServiceExceptionHandler = (httpReq, request, exception) => {
    //log your exceptions here
    ...
    //call default exception handler or prepare your own custom response
    return DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception);
};
```

Note the `v3`'s in the url: https://github.com/ServiceStackv3/ServiceStackv3/wiki